# Where is the 2.05 MJ input energy measured? (referring to the recent experiment at the National Ignition Facility (NIF))

Tags: energy, laser, measurements, fusion, x-rays

The [recent fusion experiment](https://www.llnl.gov/news/national-ignition-facility-achieves-fusion-ignition) at the National Ignition Facility delivered "2.05 megajoules (MJ) of energy to the target, resulting in 3.15 MJ of fusion energy output." But where exactly is the input energy measured?

My crude understanding is that the input energy starts out as an electric charge in a bank of capaciters, is converted into incoherent Xenon flashlight photons, becomes coherent infrared laser photons, is upconverted to coherent ultraviolet photons, and is finally converted to (incoherent?) Xray photons.

Where exactly is the 2.05 MJ measured?  They are obviously not talking about the first two stages, but is it IR or UV or even Xrays? And where in the system is it measured? There are obviously a lot of losses associated with beamforming and switching, etc.

There has been some discussion about how the neutron flux is measured and the output energy is estimated, but I've not seen anything on how the input energy is estimated.

Comment: It was the laser power: i.e. the power of all the lasers combined (optical, the UV lasers).

Comment: The whole laser generation is an excruciatingly inefficient process. Moreover, I am not aware that it is possible to make the generation of such squeezed lasers much more efficient.

Comment: We're a long way from true "break even", and even farther from a system that can create an economically practical amount of fusion energy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Where exactly is the 2.05 MJ measured?

It's the amount of UV light entering the target chamber. The reason for this *particular* measure is primarily historical.

Note that LLNL has, on occasion, redefined the location of the measurement to make results look better. For instance, in 2013 they claimed scientific breakeven by redefining the input energy as "the energy deposited in the fuel", which removed several additional very significant losses along the line so that it was something like 10 kJ of input compared to the ~2 MJ of UV. So your question does need to be asked, every time.

So, why this measure and not some other, like the 4 MJ of actual IR the laser produces? Well, this goes way back to when the laser approach (ICF) was introduced. At that time, the vast majority of fusion devices used magnets to hold the plasma (MCF) and in many of those machines, provide the heating as well. For instance, in the early [ZETA machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZETA_(fusion_reactor)), the heating of the fuel was accomplished by passing a current through the fuel, which compressed it and heated it directly, a very efficient process. In these cases, the difference between "all the energy in" and "the energy into the plasma" is not *that* much different.

Well, it turns out those approaches didn't work. You simply can't compress a plasma the needed amount, it goes wonky on you, *every* time. If we can't compress it for heating, then we some form of external heating. In modern machines, that's almost always some combination of radio frequency heaters (basically fancy microwave oven parts) and direct injection of hot fuel atoms using particle accelerators. Neither of those is super-efficient, so suddenly the amount of energy going into the system is no longer very close to the total input, those heaters are somewhere around 30 to 50% efficient. And as all of this continued, we realized that we were going to need to use superconducting magnets too, so that starts changing everything as well - the magnets no longer use much energy but the entire system of cryogenics sure does!

So now consider two reactors that both have the same total fusion output. One uses efficient heaters and superconducting magnets and makes 10 MJ of fusion output. The other uses old heaters and copper magnets and makes 20 MJ of fusion. Which is "better"? Well for most researchers, better means better plasma performance, so we don't want to have to consider all those other losses, what we want to know is "for a given amount of input energy, what amount of fusion do we get out?" And so for that comparison, we ignore all the inefficiencies upstream, the magnets, the heaters etc, and just measure the total amount of heat into and out of the plasma.

So we had this industry-wide definition of Q that was "energy into the plasma vs. energy out of the plasma".

When ICF came along it underwent a similar set of changes. Originally the calculations suggested that a 10 kJ laser would do the trick, and we would get 10 kJ or so back out. Yes, that ignores all the energy wasted in the lasers, but it sort of gets you the same thing as in the MCF case, the energy into the fuel vs the fusion out.

But when they actually tried that, it didn't work. One of the big reasons is that the IR preferentially accelerated electrons which killed the implosion, so that's when they started adding the upconversion. Now you might say we should draw the line on the other side of the converter, that the 4 MJ is the "real" amount of laser, but consider what would happen if someone suddenly invented a direct-to-UV 2 MJ laser. It would provide exactly the same amount of input to the fuel, and (we assume) the same output from the fuel, which is the real thing people are trying to measure. Sure it might use half as much electricity, but that's not telling us anything about the physics we're actually interested in - lasers are so passe after all.

So we are left with a measure that really only tells us something very specific of interest only to certain people. And that is why things like "Q engineering" and similar terms have come along.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To summarize, they are not talking about the wall plug efficiency of the lasers which somehow seems to be less than 1% e.g. 2.05 megajoules delivered from 322 megajoules of energy that went into the lasers. I assume that somehow they are still only counting the energy that went into the pellet in the 2.05 MJ number. Do you know of any reference that describes where all rest of the energy went?

Comment: The reason I ask, is that if the 2.05 MJ  is a measure of the light that enters the chamber, the less than 1 percent wall plug efficiency seems low. Many solid state lasers should be higher than that, even if doubled or tripled.

Comment: Do you think that at this scale things that are needed to initiate the reaction might be expensive in terms of energy use, but when the system is scaled up and more energy is output this is less of a concern?

Comment: @UVphoton - yes you have it correct. There is a great shanky diagram on the wiki article on NIF that shows where it all goes. And there's been considerable research into using diode lasers and/or diode lamps with existing laser glass to increase plug efficiency.

Comment: @Anyone - the issue is end-to-end "gain". So there are two parts to that, laser efficiency, and fusion dymanics. The first one is assumed to be the easy part, there is almost certainly a 10x improvement there. The other side.. no one knows. It is definitely NOT just a scale issue, making it larger doesn't improve plasma erformance in the same way that it does in magnetic approaches (due to random walk)

Answer (score 2):

Nature [writes](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-022-04440-7): "The facility used its set of 192 lasers to deliver 2.05 megajoules of energy onto a pea-sized gold cylinder containing a frozen pellet of the hydrogen isotopes deuterium and tritium.[...] The laboratory’s analysis suggests that the reaction released some 3.15 MJ of energy ... However, although the fusion reactions produced more than 3 MJ of energy — more than was delivered to the target — NIF’s lasers consumed 322 MJ of energy in the process."

So 2.05 megajoules is the estimated energy DELIVERED by the lasers into the gold cylinder.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like they are referring to the UV laser light delivered to the cylinder rather than the X-rays delivered to the spherical target.

Answer (score -2):

The lasers that excite the sample are calibrated/tested ... for many lasers it's possible to use a power meter, it is a thermal device.  So the measurement does not occur during the experiment ... they just know that each laser when fired delivers x watts or joules.

So number of lasers x joules = total power in.

Comment: So that's the laser power, or the power needed to power the laser?

Comment: Example here : https://www.gentec-eo.com/laser-power-meter?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI497eh-aB_AIVoMmUCR3WAArnEAAYASAAEgKQQPD_BwE

Comment: So what is the answer -- which power was 2.05 MJ? The power in the laser pulse, or the electric power needed to get the pulse?

Comment: Some further points of reference: the opening comments by the lab director included the statement that the total power drawn from the grid was about 300 MJ.  Presumably this gets into the capacitor bank with reasonable efficiency, But there was a statement to the effect that the lasers were not particularly designed for efficiency.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I remember the comment was that 2 Mjoules impacted the target and 3 Mjoules was the reaction.  The lasers produced the 2Mjoules into the target.

Comment: I think 2 MJ was the total emitted laser energy, and a small fraction thereof (<<1 MJ) actually is transferred to the target, while the rest "misses"